# EFS endpoint not resolving in kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have a K8S cluster launched using kops with topology=private and networking=weave. Want to mount an EFS volume to my pods but the EFS endpoint is not resolving inside pods.

I suspect because of internal routing(weave) the name resolution is not forwarding to subnet DNS server (correct me if I am wrong).

How can I resolve this issue?

Thaks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved after enabling "DNS hostname resolution" for the specific VPC.